# DDD: Loading whole aggregate would result in performance problems

Tags: domain-driven-design

Most DDD Books (e.g. Patterns and Principles of DDD) recommend strongly to load the whole aggregate when getting the data from the database. The reason for that is that aggregates are consistent boundaries.
But there common cases where this would result in overwhelming performance problems.
Here is a real example I am facing:
I have an aggregate root which is an `workobject` entity with its properties. There are other entities in this aggregate:

1. List of attached `documents` of the workobject. Each `document` is an entity.(The class `document` contains the metadata of the real document).
2. List of `comments`. Each `comment` is an entity`.
3. List of `activities`. Each `activity` is an entity which represents an activity that is done on this workobject.
4. List of `ArchivedFile`s. Each `ArchivedFile` is an entity which represents an document which is already archived in an external system. (The class `ArchivedFile` contains the metadata of the real archived file)

These entities belong to the aggregate, because changes on the `workobject` would mostly affect the state of these entities, too.
**Now I have the following problem:**
In the UI, there is a place where a user gets all the `workobject`s that are in his/her inbox. This could be more than 100 `workobject`s or even more. But it does not make sense to load the whole aggregate (`comment`s,`activies`,`document`s) for each `workobject` at that point. This would slow down the application resulting in a terrible user experience.
The idea is to show just the properties of the `workobject` to the user in a datagrid. If a user makes a specific event like clicking on a specific `workobject`, a specific form is loaded where detailed information of the specific `workobject` is loaded. That would be an appropriate point to load the whole aggregate (i.e., `comment`s,`activies`,`document`s). But most of the DDD-Books  (e.g. Patterns and Principles of DDD) warn to not use lazy loading inside an aggregate, but to load the whole aggregate when loading the aggregate root.
How should we solve this problem by still respecting the DDD-rules?

Answer (score 2):

> How should we solve this problem by still respecting the DDD-rules?

Usual answer: don't use the *aggregate* pattern when the thing you want is a *report*.

Lazy loading is a "code smell" when performing domain dynamics; if you are leaving a lot of data behind when making a change, that strongly suggests that the information left behind belongs in a *different* aggregate.

But for an operation that is effectively read only, like a report?  We're not going to be changing anything, so we don't need the constraint that ensure that our changes our correct, so we don't need the information we use to describe the constraint.

For more ideas about separating reads from writes, review the patterns described under the umbrella [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs) ("command query responsibility segregation").

Comment: I agree that lazy loading might be done for the wrong reasons and aggregate boundaries might be drawn incorrectly. But it does not have to be a smell if not all child entities of an aggregate are accessed during each business transaction that involves modifying an aggregate. I would not use lazy loading by default myself but for performance reasons it could be justified and a good fit for write intensive services. Of course under the assumption that the aggregate is designed appropriately.